# Windows 8 Metro and HLS/MPEG-DASH

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, windows-8, microsoft-metro, http-live-streaming

Does anybody know what will be the streaming format supported in Windows 8 Metro javaScript based applications?

Will they stick purely with Microsoft Smooth Streaming or they will make step forward towards HLS and/or MPEG-DASH?

BR
STeN

Comment: Here is a **Windows 8 app** sample playing **Dash stream** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089257/mpeg-dash-on-windows-8-javascript-app/19090251#19090251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go :

[image]

Hope this helps.

As for your comment you should check these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965244(v=vs.85).aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/2a17f46a-4ff4-40dd-a6b5-92480c9d2293

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithcsharp/thread/ba82f293-c245-4198-9a8e-316bf78413c3

Comment: Interesting, however it enlists codecs and file/wrapper formats (well they can be used for progressive download), but I am interesting in streaming protocols like HLS, MSS, RTSP, RTMP support. My guess is only MSS is there, while I love to see HLS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the supported formats for Metro apps:

[image: Supported audio and video formats Windows Runtime apps - Windows app development]

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx.