# MPEG-DASH on Windows 8 Javascript app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-8, streaming, mpeg-dash

Does anybody know if there are any samples or documentation for playing **dash streaming** in **Windows 8 javaScript** based applications or **Windows phone 8**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://mingfeiy.com/windows-azure-media-services-in-build-2013-dynamic-packaging-dash-support-live-streaming-and-more/

And here is a sample playing Dash stream on **windows 8 Javascript/C# applications**

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/releases

Download **Microsoft.PlayerFramework.Samples.zip**

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it fits for your solution, bit libdash is a C++ library also available for windows: http://www.bitmovin.net/libdash.html

There is also a sample player based on ffmpeg. This should also work on win 8.